# how to check whether dropdown list has all items in the given list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have got a requirement like I have got list of strings and I got dropdownlist items now we need to check whether the dropdownlist has all items in the give list of strings or not and i need to return the bool condition ...

for that purpose i have done like this ....

```
public static bool GetMacthedItems(DropDownList ddllist1, DropDownList ddllist2, string MatchedItem1, string  MatchedItem2, string MatchedItem3)
{
      bool results =true;
      List<String> list1 = new List<String> {MatchedItem1, MatchedItem2, MatchedItem3};
      if (ddllist1.SelectedValue.ToString() == MatchedItem1 && (list1.Any(x => x.Contains(ddllist2.SelectedValue.ToString()))))
      { 
          results = false;

      }
      return results;                
}
```

but the above condition is checking like whether the dropdownlist selected value is in that list or not ....

i want entire like all items in dropdownlist are in that list or not

would any one pls help on this ....

Comment: It's called a `foreach` loop

Comment: Not sure what dropdownlist you want us to check...

Comment: @banging instead of trying to be *clever*, why not convert your useless comment to a useful answer

Comment: @LukeHennerley because I like to put as much effort as the one who asked. In this case it's a ZERO. -1 from me.

Comment: @banging It contains a problem, an attempt and what the OP is trying to achieve. I class that as some form of effort, although perhaps minimal it is not 0 - your comment doesn't help anybody whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var allContained = ddlCountry.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(item => item.Value).All(item => lst.Contains(item.ToString());
```

Try this - for performance it will stop iterating once the condition is broken and return false by using a combination of `All` with `Contains`.